# Неужели оно будет работать?

Tags: шаблоны, php, проектирование

В статье Википедии про шаблон проектирования ["наблюдатель"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наблюдатель_(шаблон_проектирования)) есть пример реализации на PHP5. Мне показалось странным вот что:

```
class ProductItem implements Observer{

    public function __construct(){
            ExchangeRate::getInstance()->registerObserver($this);
    }
...
class ExchangeRate{
...
    public function registerObserver(Observer $obj){
            $this->observers[] = $obj;
    }
```

Насколько помню, :: позволяет вызвать метод класса без создания экземпляра класса, где в таком случае будет храниться атрибут observers?
Судя по тому, что в конце примера выполняется

```
ExchangeRate::getInstance()->setExchangeRate(4.5);
```

предполагается, что атрибут observers все-таки будет хранить массив прямиком в определении класса.
Вопрос - неужели оно правда работает и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего ExchangeRate - это [синглетон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29). Так что вполне себе может.

Измените в том коде что приведен в википедии на:

```
class ProductItem implements Observer {
    var $name;

        public function __construct ($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
                ExchangeRate::getInstance()->registerObserver($this);
        }

        public function notify ($obj) {
                if($obj instanceof ExchangeRate) {
                        // Update exchange rate data
                        print "Received update for "
                            . $this->name
                            . ", ExchangeRate is "
                            . $obj->getExchangeRate()
                            . "!\n";
                }
        }
}

$product1 = new ProductItem("A");
$product2 = new ProductItem("B");

ExchangeRate::getInstance()->setExchangeRate(4.5);
```

И запустите.

Comment: Да, похоже на то. Получается, в этом случае изменяется определение самого класса и класс сам хранит в себе свой же экземпляр, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да. хранит единственный экземпляр класса. В данном примере не очень понятно, но скажем для класса реализующего подключение к БД это очень удобно

Comment: Действительно работает. Забавно.

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ